# Integrate Google Analytics API Charts

Tags: python, pdf-generation, google-analytics-api

I'm writing a program to make automatic reports via Google Analytics and everything was going fine until i saw that there should be graphical images, like the Analytics web version. (Most important example, the Behavior Flow)

[image]

Is there anyway i can implement this, through code, in PDF ?

Comment: The Google Analytics API just returns data. Your going to have to find something else that will help you making charts in a pdf file.

Comment: @DaImTo thanks for the reply, i was expecting that much. But is there anyway to export it from the web ?

Comment: nope there is no other way really to create the Graphics.   There is a button to export as pdf I haven't used it much i found it well "ugly"

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned you wrote a program to download the GA data, so you have the knowledge to upload the data to a Google Spreadsheet. For more info on their api, try this URL: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/?hl=en

Once the data is in a sheet within a Google Spreadsheet, you can use Google Data Visualizations. You can put the visualizations on a chart, or you can embed them in HTML, referring to the data sheet as a datasource.

The only challenge would be the Behavioural flow. I suggest that if your page flow is fairly static, you could probably draw something dynamically using GSS's ability to alter the sizes of block images dynamically, based on data values.

Chart Gallery: 
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery?hl=en

This would entail a lot of work, as free solutions often are, but you should be able to get the result you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm already writing it in a spreadsheet and i also have seen before the Google Charts, but i had the impression that it was only for web display.